Bread oven 3 decks the element break apart
I’m a baker got experience in electrical skill.
My baking oven element was exploded and stop working. I try to repair the broken element with copper wire. However it last only few days and die again.
Second attempt: use 3 wire copper instead of 2 wire before. Still , it break after few days.
Any advice.
As the replacement element is too expensive and take too long to order. And I don’t know it will last long or not as I use steam too

Despite your wishes, you need to get a new element. That is the only safe option.

Baking/heating elements are not simple copper wires.
